# Pitch alignment for 2D textures

Tags: cuda, textures

2D textures are a useful feature of CUDA in image processing applications. To bind pitch linear memory to 2D textures, the memory has to be aligned. `cudaMallocPitch` is a good option for aligned memory allocation. On my device, the pitch returned by `cudaMallocPitch` is a multiple of 512, i.e the memory is 512 byte aligned.

The actual alignment requirement for the device is determined by `cudaDeviceProp::texturePitchAlignment` which is 32 bytes on my device.

**My question is:**

If the actual alignment requirement for 2D textures is 32 bytes, then why does `cudaMallocPitch` return 512 byte aligned memory?

Isn't it a waste of memory? For example if I create an 8 bit image of size 513 x 100, it will occupy 1024 x 100 bytes.

I get this behaviour on following systems:

1: Asus G53JW + Windows 8 x64 + GeForce GTX 460M + CUDA 5 + Core i7 740QM + 4GB RAM

2: Dell Inspiron N5110 + Windows 7 x64 + GeForce GT525M + CUDA 4.2 + Corei7 2630QM + 6GB RAM

Comment: What hardware is this on? I have always found that cudaMallocPitch honors the reported texture alignment. On the only device I have access to right now, the reported alignment in bytes is 256, and I always get multiples of 256 bytes for pitches.

Comment: I have updated the question. Added detailed system configurations in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a slightly speculative answer, but keep in mind that there are *two* alignment properties which the pitch of an allocation must satisfy for textures, one for the texture pointer and one for the texture rows. I suspect that `cudaMallocPitch` is honouring the former, defined by `cudaDeviceProp::textureAlignment`. For example:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
    const int ncases = 12;
    const size_t widths[ncases] = { 5, 10, 20, 50, 70, 90, 100,
        200, 500, 700, 900, 1000 };
    const size_t height = 10;

    float *vals[ncases];
    size_t pitches[ncases];

    struct cudaDeviceProp p;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&p, 0);
    fprintf(stdout, "Texture alignment = %zd bytes\n",
            p.textureAlignment);
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaFree(0); // establish context

    for(int i=0; i<ncases; i++) {
        cudaMallocPitch((void **)&vals[i], &pitches[i], 
            widths[i], height);
        fprintf(stdout, "width = %zd <=> pitch = %zd \n",
                widths[i], pitches[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which gives the following on a GT320M:

```
Texture alignment = 256 bytes
width = 5 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 10 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 20 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 50 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 70 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 90 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 100 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 200 <=> pitch = 256 
width = 500 <=> pitch = 512 
width = 700 <=> pitch = 768 
width = 900 <=> pitch = 1024 
width = 1000 <=> pitch = 1024
```

I am guessing that `cudaDeviceProp::texturePitchAlignment` applies to CUDA arrays.

Comment: I guess you are right. On both of my systems, i'm getting `cudaDeviceProp::textureAlignment == 512`.

Comment: As talonmies says, there is one requirement for the alignment of the texture (textureAlignment, as I recall 256 byes on older hardware, 512 bytes on current hardware), plus an alignment requirement for each row (texturePitchAlignment). In general, texturePitchAlignment <= textureAlignment. The malloc functions in CUDA return memory suitably aligned for textures.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some experiments with the memory allocation, at last I found a working solution which saves memory. If I forcefully align the memory allocated by `cudaMalloc`, `cudaBindTexture2D` works perfectly.

```
cudaError_t alignedMalloc2D(void** ptr, int width, int height, int* pitch, int alignment = 32)
{       
   if((width% alignment) != 0)
      width+= (alignment - (width % alignment));

   (*pitch) = width;

   return cudaMalloc(ptr,width* height);
}
```

The memory allocated by this function is 32 byte aligned, which is the requirement of `cudaBindTexture2D`. My memory usage is now reduced 16 times and all the CUDA functions, which use 2D textures are also working correctly.

Here is a small utility function to get the currently selected CUDA device pitch alignment requirement.

```
int getCurrentDeviceTexturePitchAlignment()
{
   cudaDeviceProp prop;
   int currentDevice = 0;

   cudaGetDevice(&currentDevice);

   cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop,currentDevice);

   return prop.texturePitchAlignment;
}
```

Comment: It works fine as you said, but does it honor the requirement for coalesced access to the memory?